# Как установить границу на верхнюю панель JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing

Хочу улучшить внешний вид JInternalFrame. Вот что получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код:

```
frameForRead = new MyJInternalFrame("Чтение задачи");
    UIManager.put("InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground", Color.white);
    UIManager.put("InternalFrame.inactiveTitleBackground", Color.WHITE);
    UIManager.put("InternalFrame.border", new LineBorder(Color.gray, 3));
    UIManager.put("InternalFrame.borderDarkShadow", Color.BLACK);
    ((BasicInternalFrameUI)frameForRead.getUI()).getNorthPane().setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 3));
    javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI ui = new javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI(
            frameForRead);
    frameForRead.setUI(ui);
```

Следующая строка срабатывает хорошо:

```
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.border", new LineBorder(Color.gray, 3));
```

Но граница появляется не у всего JInternalFrame. Она не появляется у верхней панели(где кнопки свернуть, развернуть, закрыть). В итоге верхняя панель сливается с фоном JDesktopPane. В идеале мне нужно установить тень. Пробую так:

```
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.borderDarkShadow", Color.BLACK);
```

Не работает. Сойдет уже и просто граница на верхней панели. Пробую установить ее следующим образом:

```
((BasicInternalFrameUI)frameForRead.getUI()).getNorthPane().setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 3));
```

Не работает. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно установить границу на верхнюю панель JInternalFrame? 
Если это все же делается методом UIManager.put() то вот список свойств для JInternalFrame:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingaJInternalFrameLookandFeel.htm
Но я уж и не знаю какое из них выбирать, вроде все попробовал.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему. Оказывается вот эти строчки надо было поменять местами.

У меня было так:

```
((BasicInternalFrameUI)frameForRead.getUI()).getNorthPane().setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 3));
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI ui = new javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI(
        frameForRead);
frameForRead.setUI(ui);
```

А надо вот так:

```
BasicInternalFrameUI ui = new BasicInternalFrameUI(frameForRead);
frameForRead.setUI(ui);
((BasicInternalFrameUI) frameForRead.getUI()).getNorthPane().setBorder(
            new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1));
```